Area of a trapezium given 2 bases and a diagonal
I want to calculate the area of a trapezoid given the 2 bases and one of his diagonals. I searched on some other questions but I only find the solution given also the other diagonal. Is it possible to calculate the area with only one of them?

Here's an animation showing a family of trapezoids with the same lengths for the two parallel sides and one diagonal. Clearly, the area is not constant. Therefore, there can't exist a formula that computes the area of the trapezoid only from those three lengths.
